# Deixar div com height auto e com o bottom setado

Tags: html, css

Existe alguma forma de deixar a *div* com o *bottom* setado sem que ele deixe o `height: 100%`?

Enquanto houver pouco conteúdo (como no exemplo), o *height* deve ficar *auto*, mas quando houver bastante conteúdo, não poderá encostar no fundo da tela (por isso o `bottom: 10px`).

O problema é que quando eu seto o *bottom*, automaticamente o *height* ocupa toda tela (mesmo deixando ele *auto*).

Teria alguma forma de contornar isso?

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cara se o elemento esta a 10px do topo da pagina e 10px do bottom logicamente ele vai ocupar todo o espaço sente a desse intervalo

Comment: @hugocsl, entendi, dessa forma então não vai funcionar. Mas tu entendeu a ideia? Teria alguma forma de fazer funcionar sem precisar adicionar mais uma div pai (pensei em contornar desse jeito)?

Comment: @Sam, acabei resolvendo com JS mesmo. Não encontrei outra forma com CSS.

Comment: Acho que com jQuery ficaria mais fácil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução é usar a função `calc()` no `max-height` (então não precisa do `bottom` e do `height`).

Basta subtrair os `100vh` (altura do viewport) pelos `20px` (distância do `top` + distância desejada do `bottom`):

```
max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
```

Caso haja alguma outra propriedade de espaçamento no elemento, como `padding-top` ou `padding-bottom`, é preciso somar esses valores aos `20px`. Por exemplo, se o elemento tiver um `padding: 20px`, ficaria:

```
max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
```

Ou seja, os `20px` normais + `20px` do `padding-top` + `20px` do `padding-bottom`, totalizando `60px`.

Veja um exemplo sem o `padding`:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test10</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Agora um exemplo com `padding`:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test10</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, utilize `max-height: 90vh;` no lugar de `max-height: 100%;` logo a lista utilizará no máximo 90/100 da altura do viewport da página, altere o valor como quiser para que a lista se adapte bem ao tamanho da tela.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 90vh;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```